# Please merge my Mathematics Stack Exchange accounts

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, unregistered-users

I have, as they seem to be called, a "cookie-only" account or two on Mathematics Stack Exchange. Can they be merged with my account here: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/179960/human which is associated with a Stack Exchange account? Thank you!

(Note: I would have posted this on Mathematics meta, but I don't have 5 reputations with my Stack Exchange account.)

Comment: Note that you don't need 5 reputation on Meta Stack Exchange in order to post on the Mathematics Meta - you just need 5 reputation on Mathematics itself, which by the looks of it you already have.

Comment: You don't need to post on any meta; rather, use the [contact us](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link in the footer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to get merges handled is to use the [contact us](https://math.stackexchange.com/contact) link. Select "I need to merge user profiles" in the "What can we help you with?" menu, then provide us links to the profiles that you would like merged. (Make sure you are logged into one of the accounts when you contact us – it expedites the process of making sure the accounts both belong to you.)

Comment: I submitted the form, but because I can no longer find a link to my "cookie-only" account, I had to select "Other" as the reason of contact. Thank you!